# NIntegrate integrand evaluating to non-numerical values

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, vector-calculus

I am having trouble with the `NIntegrate` at the bottom. I've tried using `NumericQ` in different ways but keep getting an error message (`NIntegrate::inumr`) saying that it evaluates to non-numerical values for all sampling points.

For more context the problem is [question 9 here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihx6XExJnVAhVD3yYKHbhWADEQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.colorado.edu%2Famath%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fattached-files%2Fcomet_project_0.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGe4_JULYSvA68QythSJ7tJtwFR1A) .

```
rOrb[t_] = 
  {-1769.42 - 5230.58 Cos[0.0001 t] - 536.31 Sin[0.0001 t], 
   1233.56 - 6233.56 Cos[0.0001 t] + 4499.51 Sin[0.0001 t], 
   4187.62 + 5812.38 Cos[0.0001 t]};

T[t_] := Simplify[ rOrb'[t] / Norm[ rOrb'[t] ], t ϵ Reals];

vOrb[t_] := D[rOrb[t], t];

vdust[x_, y_, z_] := 
  1.7 {E^(-4 10^(-8) x^2), E^(-4 10^(-8) y^2), e^(-1.6  10^(-9) z^2)};

ρdust = 2 10^-6;

NIntegrate[((vOrb[t] - vdust[rOrb[t]]).T[t]) ρdust rOrb[t], {t, 
  0, 20000 π}]
```

Comment: What happens when you plug in a numerical value for your integration variable into your integrand? (E.g. for `NIntegrate[f, {x, 0, 1}]` try something like `f /. x -> 0.5`, substituting your integrand for `f`, your variable for `x`, and numerical value in the interval of integration for `0.5`.)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant, but I coudn't get this to work either.
    



  `f = ((vOrb[t] - vdust[rOrb[t]]).T[t]) \[Rho]dust rOrb[t];
    NIntegrate[f, {x, 0, 0.5}]`



@MichaelE2

Comment: I meant for you to plug in an appropriate floating-point number for your variable, which is `t` not `x`.  Use `ReplaceAll` to substitute a number for a variable as mentioned (e.g. `...<integrand>... /. t -> 1.`).

Comment: Thank you. I used ReplaceAll[t -> 1.][f] with f saved as my integrand. That gives me the a vector of a bunch of different numbers that was too long to paste in here ( x component being ` {-0.014 (-0.118 (-0.0535 \ - vdust[{-7000.053, -4999.55, 9999.999}]) - 0.0001282 (-0.0000581 - vdust[{-7000.0536, -4999.55, 9999.999}]) + 0.99298 (0.45001 - vdust[{-7000.053, -4999.55, 9999.9999}])) ` 
What can I do with that now?
@MichaelE2

Comment: You seem to have a `vdust` in there: that's not a number.  It's telling you `vdust` is not defined right, or you're not using it right; otherwise, it would evaluate to a number.  There are two choices: change how you define `vdust` or change how you are using it.  The first way is fairly simple: just add braces to the def.: `vdust[{x_, y_, z_}] :=...`

Answer (score 2):

There is two errors in your definition of `vdust`. The following is correct:

```
vdust[{x_, y_, z_}] :=  1.7 {E^(-4 10^(-8) x^2), E^(-4 10^(-8) y^2), 
                             E^(-1.6  10^(-9) z^2)};
```

First you want to define the argument as a vector because the output of rOrb is a vector. Second one of the `E`'s was and `e`, which is undefined.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!